# How to wait until Callback has data?

Tags: android, callback, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to use Retrofit and OkHttp to make request to a server. I have the next class **"AutomaticRequest.java"** which has a request to get videos from a server.

```
public class AutomaticRequest {

    public void getVideos(final AutomaticCallback callback){

        MediaproApiInterface service = ApiClient.getClient();
        Call<List<AutomaticVideo>> call = service.getAllVideos();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AutomaticVideo>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AutomaticVideo>> call, Response<List<AutomaticVideo>> response) {
                List<AutomaticVideo> automaticVideoList = response.body();
                callback.onSuccessGettingVideos(automaticVideoList);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AutomaticVideo>> call, Throwable t) {
                callback.onError();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I've created the next class **"AutomaticCallback.java"** to retrieve data.

```
public interface AutomaticCallback {
    void onSuccessGettingVideos(List<AutomaticVideo> automaticVideoList);
    void onError();
}
```

I'm calling the request from a fragment like the next way:

```
public class AllVideosFragment extends Fragment {

    ...
    AutomaticCallback callback;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allvideos, container, false);

        new AutomaticRequest().getVideos(callback);

        return view;
    }

    ...

}
```

How I can wait until the callback has data to update the UI?? Thank you.

Comment: a synchronous request will automatically wait for the response, but it will block the main thread until then. You should make an asynchronous request and, upon receiving the response, update the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the AutomaticCallback interface on your fragment like:

```
    public class AllVideosFragment extends Fragment implements AutomaticCallback {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allvideos, container, false);

        new AutomaticRequest().getVideos(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    void onSuccessGettingVideos(List<AutomaticVideo> automaticVideoList){
       // use your data here
    }

    @Override
    void onError(){
      // handle the error
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass callback to the method getVideos, to do that?

Comment: Yes, and since your fragment implements the callback, you pass the fragment to the method aka 'this'.

Comment: Thank you. Gracias (Spanish)